# Does adding a serviceWorker really break appCache?

Tags: service-worker, html5-appcache

We had a nice mobile web app, with an offline mode working with appCache. Then we added a serviceWorker, [following this doc](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/add-to-home-screen/#0), so as to get the "add to home screen" prompt on android, and **boom: appCache is broken**. The appCache clearly still loads, and we get the applicationCached event, but as soon as we try and use the app offline, we get connection errors. Nothing is served from appCache.

So far I haven't turned up any information about this. It smells very final. Can serviceWorkers cohabit with appCache, or am I being gently encouraged to port our offline mode to serviceWorker before anything will work again?

Answer (score 0):

**Yep. [ServiceWorker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1163545) breaks [appCache](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=410665).**

[sw-appcache-behavior](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sw-appcache-behavior) on NPM promises to provide a migration path, but serviceWorker is not yet supported in mobile IOS. There's also [jakecache.js](https://github.com/kenchris/jakecache).